# Searching SQL query after using INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

When displaying the table without the search it prints perfectly, when when adding the where query (which works fine in other search tables without inner join included) it produces a syntax error. Here is the code:

```
SELECT Date_entered, photo1, photo2, UserName, reserveName, species FROM Plant_Reserves 
                        INNER JOIN Plant_Species ON Plant_Reserves.plantID = Plant_Species.plantID 
                        INNER JOIN reserves ON Plant_Reserves.reserveID = reserves.reserveID
                        ORDER BY UserName WHERE UserName LIKE '%$search%'
```

Here is a copy of the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE UserName LIKE '%zz%'' at line 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where` comes before `order by`

```
SELECT Date_entered, photo1, photo2, UserName, reserveName, species 
FROM Plant_Reserves 
INNER JOIN Plant_Species ON Plant_Reserves.plantID = Plant_Species.plantID 
INNER JOIN reserves ON Plant_Reserves.reserveID = reserves.reserveID
WHERE UserName LIKE '%$search%'
ORDER BY UserName
```

The defined order of keywords is

```
select
from 
join
where
group by
having
order by
limit
```